# How to extract an item from a javascript event in scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class WoolRich(scrapy.Spider):
    name= "WoolRich_Spider"
    allowed_domains = ['woolrich.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.woolrich.com/men/?sort=featured&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
    links = response.css('li.product> article> figure> a::attr(href)').extract()
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link,
                             callback=self.parse_of_individual_page)

    next_page=LinkExtractor(allow=[''], deny=['sort', 'size', 'Size', 'fsnf'])
    links = next_page.extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link.url,
                             callback=self.parse)

   # response.css('div.productView-image').extract()

def parse_of_individual_page(self, response):
    self.arbi = {
        'Product Name': response.css('h1.productView-title::text').extract(),
        'Style': response.css('.productView-product > div:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)::text').extract(),
        'Price': response.css('span.price::text')[0].extract(),
        'Size': response.css('span.form-option-variant::text').extract(),
        'Features': response.css('#features-content > li::text').extract(),
        'Description': response.css('#details-content::text').extract(),
        'Path from home': response.css('a.breadcrumb-label::text').extract(),
        'Image links': response.css('div.zoom> a::attr(data-zoom-image)').extract()



    }
    yield self.arbi
```

This is the entire code. I cannot retrieve the color of the products as they are dynamic. Take a look at this URl for example: https://www.woolrich.com/mens-wool-stag-shirt-jac-6138/

It has multiple colors. Need the name of the colors only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but you need to scrape page data that is only displayed after certain Javascript code runs. The HTML is not loaded right as your Scrapy request is finished, right? I don't know if it's the best solution but you can use a WebDriver like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction) which essentially mimics a browser and then you can scrape the page after it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.css('label.form-option-swatch> span::attr(title)').extract()
```

This solved the problem. I overlooked this line in the HTML